# Create custom template for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adt, freemarker

I'm working with Android Studio and i want to create a new template project to add in the initial screen (quick start section). How can i do it?

[image: quick start]

I've already created a template module following [this](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/resources-and-tools/6845-android-adt-template-format-document.html)